# Can we merge Lead using Mobile phone and other custom fields

Tags: leads, duplicate-management

In my org we have lots of duplicate Leads, few of them have same Email others have same MobilePhone and some have same value in custom field.

Now when i tried to Find these duplicate Leads; it only allows to find duplicates using few fields as shown in image.
eg. Name, Email, Phone, Company...

[image]

So can I find duplicates using fields other than default fields? Please suggest :)

Comment: Have you enabled global search for other fields of Lead Object?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, I have not changed any settings in global search but I can search using any lead field currently. So that means yes they are enabled for global search.

Comment: So Your problem is solved?

Comment: No...allowing fields for global search is not solution to this problem...as of now i think its not possible :)  Thanks buy the way for reply

Comment: Your welcome :)